# Include a location header in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I read in a post that it is ideal to put that it is a good standard to include a Location header that points to the URL of the new resource (newly created via POST). My problem is I do not know how to include it.

I am using a class-based views using the APIView and my code in the view is:

```
class ListArtists(APIView):
    serializer_class = ArtistSerializer
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        _array = Artist.objects.filter()
        serializer = self.serializer_class(_array, many=True)
        if serializer.data:
            _status = status.HTTP_200_OK
        else:
            _status = status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT
        return Response(standardResponse(data=serializer.data), status=_status)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(standardResponse(data=serializer.data), status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response(standardResponse(errors=serializer.errors))
artist = ListArtists.as_view()
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include

from store import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^artists/', views.artist, name='artists-list'),
]
```

P.S.

Every time I throw a request using my Advanced REST Client this is the response that I receive:

```
Date: Sat, 23 Jul 2016 10:54:23 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.10
Vary: Accept, Cookie
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Type: application/json
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
```

Comment: You can add [headers to the response object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/#setting-header-fields) before returning it.

Comment: Could you provide a code please..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can [add arbitrary headers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/#setting-header-fields) to a `Response` object, like so:

```
def post(self, request, format=None):
    serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        obj = serializer.save()
        response = Response(standardResponse(data=serializer.data), 
                            status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        # If you have defined a get_absolute_url method on your model, then
        # you can use that to get a URL for the new object
        response['Location'] = obj.get_absolute_url()
        return response
```

Comment: Now this is the answer t hat I am looking for! Thanks!

Comment: Hi, Can we also remove any header field manually, in DRF, If yes can you please throw some light here:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68706989/how-to-remove-location-from-the-header-options-in-drf

Answer (score 1):

The default of the `create`-function in a `CreateModelMixin` calls `self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)` (implemented [here](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/1db19f4b2d1500894448634852e02f73043382e4/rest_framework/mixins.py#L28)).

We can see that by default `api_settings.URL_FIELD_NAME` would be included. `URL_FIELD_NAME` is by default `url`.

When changing this value in your `settings.py` to, for example, `id` will now include the `id` in the Location header:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "URL_FIELD_NAME": "id",  # This field is used in the Location header on a created resource
}
```

Resulting POST request:

```
HTTP 201 Created
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Location: fe36f285-ab38-4ef9-b707-425f03a7cdc5
Vary: Accept

{
    "id": "fe36f285-ab38-4ef9-b707-425f03a7cdc5",
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those using the `drf` `CreateModelMixin` the `view` has to look something like that:

In case you do want an empty body in the response:

```
class MyView(mixins.CreateModelMixin, generics.GenericAPIView):

    serializer_class = MySerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        default_response = self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return Response(headers={'Location': reverse("get_enpoint_name", args=[default_response.data['id']], request=self.request)})
```

In case the response body has to include the objects data as specified in the serializer:

```
class MyView(mixins.CreateModelMixin, generics.GenericAPIView):

    serializer_class = MySerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_success_headers(self, data):
        try:
            return {'Location': reverse("customer", args=[data['id']], request=self.request)}
        except (TypeError, KeyError):
            return {}
```

Always open for improvements!