# How to remove `LOCATION` from the header options in DRF?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have a serializer which contains a `URL` field, By default, if there is a field named as `URL` then the value of this field is added in the HEADER option as LOCATION, I don't want to do this, and would like to remove the `LOCATION` option from the header.

This is my serializer:-

```py
class DemoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Demo
        fields = ('type', 'protocol', ---- 'url', 'somefield')
```

Now when the above serializer is used with POST/PUT/PATCH request to send data, I get this as response:-
[image]

Is there any method, or way I can remove the `LOCATION` option from the header, without effecting my other serializers and view in the project??

Comment: To clarify, this is the  response in the screenshot, not the request, correct? Also, will you post it as text rather than a screenshot?

Comment: Yes, you are right @Code-Apprentice, the screenshot is of response, with header options, but, if i post the text, when I do curl/http only the data is returned in response, so that's for ease I posted the screenshot.

Comment: I don't understand what editing your question here with text has to do with curl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In View which is you want to remove Location header, you should override get_success_headers function.

Default

```py
    def get_success_headers(self, data):
        try:
            return {'Location': str(data[api_settings.URL_FIELD_NAME])}
        except (TypeError, KeyError):
            return {}
```

Override

```py
    def get_success_headers(self, data):
        return {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change or set the `URL_FIELD_NAME` to `None` which is used for setting the Location header:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "URL_FIELD_NAME": None,  # This field is used in the Location header on a created resource
}
```